# What date does a moon phase guide represent?

Tags: preparation, resources

I'm trying to plan a night trip around the New Moon to have my first go at [Astrophotography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophotography), so I'm looking at [Moongiant](http://www.moongiant.com/phase/2/26/2017).

I'm trying to learn what date a moon phase guide represents. For example, I don't know if the New Moon on Feb 26th means there's no Moon on the night of the 25th / morning of the 26th, or the night of the 26th / morning of the 27th.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the way that it works, is the the time at which it peaks/goes darkest is marked as the day that it happens.

In this case, on Feb 26th, according to this [page](http://www.moongiant.com/moonphases/February/2017/), the New Moon will peak at **14:58 UTC**.

In other words, you're better off using a resource that doesn't just say the day but the actual time. Then depending on where you are in the world will determine if the New Moon peaks closer to the night prior or the night after.

Comment: 14:58 UTC is like 10am EST to 7am PST. So for us in the USA we'd go with the night of the 25th / morning of the 26th then? Not sure if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: In PST that's 6:58 am, so the night of the 25th would be the closet to the peak time. Hope that makes sense